# Options when network admin blocked download.microsoft.com

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, wsl2

After few days investigating, apparently my boarding house owner (also he's the network admin of the building) blocked download.microsoft.com, that's why I can't install WSL2, can't update, can't install anything on microsoft store (install button doesn't respond at all), what are my options to update my windows 10 (at least until WSL2 running)? (weirdly I can't even ssh using ssh command line/putty on my server that usually I used to tunnel, it works on my linux PC that are on the same network but doesn't work on windows)

I'm using Windows 10 19041.423 (installed a week ago), previously fully using linux for years.

Comment: Live somewhere else, that owner is nuts.

Comment: Also contact the owner as we cannot solve this kind of problem.  Look also at having your own Internet (ISP Hotspot).

Comment: Maybe ask for it to be unblocked?

Comment: @Virtuality I didn't know the problem until he said it when I asked on boarding house group chat whether other tenant have the same problem when accessing download.microsoft.com XD that he blocked windows update websites to make whole network stable

Answer (score 1):

You can use a VPN software. There are some free VPNs available as well.